# string find_first does not update string

Tags: c++, string, replace, find

Hey i have a litle problem , this program works as intended

It takes a string test , replaces all the "!" for "."and identifies were the "?" and the "." are , then it puts does values on an vector and it prints only the parts of the string that are questions, it works fine if the string does not have any "!" but if it has it can not identify all the questions any more.

If the string is like this, it works

```
std::string test ("ver. what? lol. o que e isto? nao sei. ola? haha. why? adeus. oi! an? haha. lool! ");
```

But if it is like this , it does not find the questions.

```
std::string test ("ver! what? lol! o que e isto? nao sei! ola? haha. why? adeus. oi! an? haha. lool! ");
```

But this part of the ode was suppose to replace all the "!" with "."so that the code would work

```
while (found!=std::string::npos)
{
  //std::cout << found << '\n';
  test[found]='.';
  found=test.find_first_of("!",found+1);
  std::cout << test << '\n';
}
```

Thanks for the help

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    std::vector< int > interrogation ;
    std::vector< int > dot;

    string look = "?";
    string look_again = ".";
    std::string test ("ver! what? lol! o que e isto? nao sei! ola? haha. why? adeus. oi! an? haha. lool! ");
    std::size_t found = test.find_first_of("!");

    string::size_type pos = test.find(look);
    string::size_type sop = test.find(look_again);

    while (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        //std::cout << found << '\n';
        test[found]='.';
        found=test.find_first_of("!",found+1);
        std::cout << test << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << test << '\n';

    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {

        int a = pos ;

        //cout << " . found at : " << sop << std::endl;

        interrogation.push_back(a);

        string fragment = test.substr (0 , pos  );    // works
        //cout << fragment << endl ;

        pos = test.find(look, pos + 1);
    }

    while (sop != std::string::npos)
    {

        int b = sop;

        //cout << " ? found at : " << pos << std::endl;

        dot.push_back(b);

        string fragment2 = test.substr (0 , sop) ;    // works
        //cout << fragment2 << endl ;

        sop = test.find(look_again, sop + 1);
    }

    while( interrogation.size() > 0){

        std::cout << test << '\n';

        while(dot.back() > interrogation.back())
        {
            cout << "dot.pop_back" << endl;
            dot.pop_back();
        }

        string fragment = test.substr (dot.back() + 1,  interrogation.back() -     dot.back());
        cout << "question with dot \n" << fragment << endl ;

        interrogation.pop_back() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What're you trying to do, and what about your code doesn't work? I just see a lot of comments that say "works"

Comment: have you read what i said before the code?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the first `.` position (-> `string::size_type sop = test.find(look_again);`) before you replace `!` with `.` (-> `while (found!=std::string::npos) { ... }`). Do the assignment to `sop` after the `while`-loop that replaces `!` with `.`.

Comment: If the string is like this, it works

   std::string test ("ver. what? lol. o que e isto? nao sei. ola? haha. why? adeus. oi! an? haha. lool! ");

The code works fine without the "!" in the string , but when i put them on the string the code fails and i dont know why
because they should have been replaced anyway
But if it is like this , it does not find the questions.

std::string test ("ver! what? lol! o que e isto? nao sei! ola? haha. why? adeus. oi! an? haha. lool! ");

But this part of the code was suppose to replace all the "!" with "."so that the code would work

Comment: I got what you said and you are right it works now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code if anyone wants it, this code finds questions in a string that is assigned to a text file named questions_to_find and them saves the questions to a text file  file named saved_question

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

int main (){

std::vector< int > interrogation ;
std::vector< int > dot;

string look = "?";
string look_again = ".";

std::string test;


  ifstream myfile ("questions_to_find.txt");

    while ( getline (myfile,test) )
    {
      cout << test << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();

std::size_t found = test.find_first_of("!");

  while (found!=std::string::npos)
  {
    //std::cout << found << '\n';
    test[found]='.';
    found=test.find_first_of("!",found+1);
    //std::cout << test << '\n';
  }

string::size_type pos = test.find(look);
string::size_type sop = test.find(look_again);

while (pos != std::string::npos)
{

int a = pos ;

//cout << " . found at : " << sop << std::endl;

interrogation.push_back(a);

string fragment = test.substr (0 , pos  );    // works
//cout << fragment << endl ;

  pos = test.find(look, pos + 1);
}

while (sop != std::string::npos)
{

int b = sop;

//cout << " ? found at : " << pos << std::endl;

dot.push_back(b);

string fragment2 = test.substr (0 , sop) ;    // works
//cout << fragment2 << endl ;

  sop = test.find(look_again, sop + 1);
}

std::cout << test << '\n';

while( interrogation.size() > 0){

//std::cout << test << '\n';

while(dot.back() > interrogation.back())
{
    //cout << "dot.pop_back" << endl;
   dot.pop_back();
}

string fragment = test.substr (dot.back() + 1,  interrogation.back() -     dot.back());
cout << "Question found. \n" << fragment << endl ;

// to save text

string save = "saved_question.txt" ;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (save.c_str(), ios::app);
myfile <<  fragment << endl;
myfile.close();

//cout << "Question saved in text file" << endl;

interrogation.pop_back() ;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to output the sentence in the string that are questions, I think you're doing too much work in there when you do the find&replace '!' with '.', find '?', and by then outputting the sentences that are questions in multiple loops.

Just do a single loop to get only the questions from the whole string.

```
void function(string str) {
    string sentence = "";
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if(str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!')
        sentence = ""; // the sentence is not a question so clear the sentence
      else if(str[i] == '?') {
        sentence.push_back(str[i]);
        cout << sentence << endl;
      }
      else
        sentence.push_back(str[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't get really well why you are storing the punctuations(.?) or its index(in the string) in a vector. Perhaps to have an easier way of parsing/splitting the string that needs to be displayed?